# Checkbox in the first td of the tr(only one) gives undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a form in a jsp. It contains dynamic tr's. Tr's can be one or more. Problem comes up when there is only one tr. If more than one tr's also all input elements will have same name.

```
function getRowIndex( el ) {
            while( (el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' );
            if( el ) 
            return el.rowIndex - 1;
      }

function enableDisableRow(rowIndex){
           if(document.formName.check_all[rowIndex].checked == true){
                 document.formName.text_all[rowIndex].disabled = false;
           }
}


<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="check_all"       onclick="enableDisableRow(getRowIndex(this))" />
      </td>
          <input type="text" name="text_all" value="Hello" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Problem is I get `document.formName.check_all.checked` as undefined when there is only one row.

Comment: Where is `formName` in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.formName.check_all[rowIndex].checked == true) {
    document.formName.text_all[rowIndex].disabled = false;
}
```

`document.formName.check_all` does not return an array or a `nodeList`. It's simply the `input` element. So don't use array indices on it. The other problem is the you don't have an element or form named `"formName"`. Try this instead:

```
function getRowIndex(el) {
    while ((el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr');
    if (el) return el.rowIndex - 1;
}

function enableDisableRow(rowIndex) {
    if (document.formName.check_all.checked == true) {
        document.formName.text_all.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<form name="formName">
    <table name="">
       <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="check_all" onclick="enableDisableRow(getRowIndex(this))" />
          </td>
           <td>
              <input type="text" name="text_all" value="Hello" />
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Then you'll just break it when there are multiple boxes.

Answer (score 0):

`document.formName.check_all` will only return a `nodeList` when there's more than one element with the same name in the form, otherwise it will simply return the `input` element and using the array notation on it will return `undefined`, resulting in a syntax error when you try to access its properties.

Provided you don't have a different table inside the same form with the same input names, you can use the [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) DOM method which will always return a `nodeList`, or a compatible array-like structure in older browsers.

```
function getRowIndex(el) {
    while ((el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr');
    if (el) return el.rowIndex; //NOTE: I've also removed the -1 here
}
function enableDisableRow(rowIndex) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check_all'),
        textboxes = document.getElementsByName('text_all');

    if (checkboxes[rowIndex].checked) {
        textboxes[rowIndex].disabled = false;
    }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qEaje/) - Note that I'm using jQuery solely for adding dynamic rows, so you can test with both single row and multiple rows.